# Service that rename files and make folders for designers workflow

Tags: android, user-interface, automation, user-experience

I'm an UX/UI designer. I usally export Android assets all in one folder (because I can't do anything else) with the suffix of the resolution. I need a service that take all the files with the "**-mdpi**" suffix, rename it and put all the renamed files in one folder called "**drawable-mdpi**".

The same process with the "**-hdpi**" suffix, the "**-xhdpi**" suffix and finally the "**-xxhdpi**".

The result are four folders with the files inside, all with the same name.

I've tryied to create this service with Automator, but without  any results.

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Upcoming release Android Studio 1.3 will convert .svg to all res folder with proper size

Comment: Thnx for the tip! But now? How can I manage all these images?

Comment: Photoshop allow you to export correct image with predefined size using layer name. It's in `File > Generate > Picture file `

Comment: I know, but the hard thing, with Photoshop, is upscale if you design at 1x. What's your workflow? I usually draw at 1x but if I export my assets with Photoshop the autput are blurry images if I told PS to export at 1,5x, at 2x and at 3x. The 1x images are perfect.

Comment: Depends, for me it's best to have high res base ressources that you downscale. In general, it's better to have vector icon for example so it will always looks greate at any scale.